# Searching a Grid of Tiles With MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a series of rows in MySQL with a 'location' column, which represents the location of an object on a two dimensional xy grid.  I want to search the table for rows with a location which is within a given distance of a certain tiles.

For example, if I ran a search within 10 tiles of [34,56], that would return any rows with a 'location' value between [24-44 and 46-66].

My solution to this problem was to create an array (using for loops) with all of the possible tiles that would fall within that search term, and then query MySQL thusly:

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE localcoordinate IN ('$rangearray')"
```

This solution works fine, but is very resource intensive.  I'd like to be able to run many searches at a distance of hundreds or thousands of tiles.  Can anyone suggest a better approach that might run faster?

Comment: As soon as I posted this, it occurred to me that one effective solution would be to break the x-y column into two fields, and run a query: "SELECT * FROM table WHERE localcoordinateX in ($xvalues) AND localcoordinateY in ($yvalues)."  This would save a lot of resources currently being consumed in the for loops constructing $rangearray.  This will certainly help, but are there any other suggestions?

Comment: If that solved your problem, post it as an answer.

Comment: It didn't really 'solve' the problem.  It's an improvement on my old approach, but I'm wondering if there are any further improvements that I could implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I improved my resource consumption by a factor of 100 by implementing the following strategy changes.

1) I broke the xy coordinate into two fields within the table.

2) I searched natively in MySQL with the "BETWEEN" function.

The final query looked something like this.  You can extrapolate the data structure from the query.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE localcoordinateX BETWEEN $x-lo AND $x-hi AND localcoordinateY BETWEEN $y-lo AND $y-hi.
```

I should have thought of this the first time around but I didn't. Just the act of posting to stack exchange got me thinking clearly again, though!